# Which image preset to use?

Tags: 7, media

I created a new image style with scale and crop effect. When I create a node and apply that image style to the image included with the node, I can see parts of the image are cut out.

This happens specially when the image is large (vertically or horizontally). I need to use an image style which does not cut the image and resizes it properly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't you just want a scale then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the "Scale" option, and only set 1 of the variables. Either width OR height. You can leave 1 of them blank. This way the image styles will respect the aspect ratio of your images. I usually only set width, and leave height blank.

Don't use "Scale and crop" as crop will cut parts off your image to make it fit the size you specified.